Excel formula to convert text to date (varying inputs)
I'm having a challenge in actually finding a working formula to convert the below inputs into a date format. I'm on excel for Mac. Inputs are in these forms:

1/1/2024
1/16/2024
12/12/2023
12/1/2023

I've tried multiple formulas but couldn't quite make it work. To get the year is easy, but to extract the month and day based on their dynamic position was something I could not accomplish.
Maybe someone is an excel wizard and can help.
Thanks

What exactly are you trying to achieve? These inputs are already in a date format. Do you want 3 seperate cells with day, month and year? or do you want to change the formatting (through formulas)?

Have you tried using the Text To Columns from data tab, to convert the same to date. It works usually when dates are stored as text.

If they are stored as text then just try =--A1. This will convert text to date.

You dont even need a formula to convert the same if they are actually stored as text, because when you use Text To Columns and select the data type as date with MDY it converts to true excel dates and stays in the same cell. and takes less than a few.

I want to automate via a formular as I have a living document. Text to Columns works almost, but not all the time. I guess the varying input causes problem on that function. I do not get consistent outcomes here.

I've tried =--A1 but as well, it only converts some fields, and some not. The input is an export from Salesforce...

Then you can use the formula as mentioned in answers. using DATEVALUE() or use the following =LET(α, --TEXTSPLIT(A1,"/"),DATE(INDEX(α,,3), INDEX(α,,1), INDEX(α,,2))) ah okay you are working with Salesforce data then text to columns wont work you need to split all of it and then join with a formula, and as far it works with some specific date formats only.

@Borinho could you post few examples with the expected output, what should be for 4/6/2023 will it be 4th June 2023 or 6th April 2023, and if all the text formatted dates starts with months then there is no confusion, but if not then please show some examples.

Expected outcome would be just be any date format - I wouldn't really care actually

Have you tried the formula that i have commented in my second last comment.

Problem is probably due to mismatch between the date format (regional settings) of your computer and the Salesforce output. Make sure they match. See Salesforce: Change the date format for each User

Do you know at least if the dates provided are real dates (numeric) or text (strings)? To get the year is easy how are you getting the year? What would be the expected output of each one of the values you've provided?

Have you tried =YEAR(A1), =MONTH(A1) and =DAY(A1), replace A1 with whatever cells you have the dates in and see what results you get.

Yes, but this didn't work either due to the varying input format.

I've solved this now by changing the report that Salesforce produces to spit out dd-mm-yyyy now - which Excel can parse now. Thanks for all your help and ideas!

You can use the DateValue() function for getting the date value out of the text.
Afterwards you might need to alter the text formatting in order to get it back into date format: in my case (Dutch language), I went for the dd/mm/jjjj;@ format, turning your example 1/1/2024 into 01/01/2024:

I guess, for an English locale, you might need a format like dd/mm/yyyy;@.

Thanks for your suggestion, but this doesn't work either. I think when the input is M/DD/YYYY Excel cannot understand it and throws and #VALUE error... Hence I was trying to get this solved via a formula.

I would rather suggest you to change your locale in such a way that the date is recognised correctly. Working with formulae in order to get things to work is a big burden, asking for problems.

I would - system is locked down, no can do unfortunately.
